# Method not allowed exception on form tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel and creating an ecomm website using laravel Shopping cart [library](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) and [Laravelcollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) 5.4. I'm currently stuck on Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException which appears on a single delete button but if we create another delete button the second button works fine with the same code, whereas the first button creates the error.  Please help me with this error.

My Error is:
[image]
My Route file is:

```
    <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/','FrontController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('shop', 'FrontController@shop')->name('shop');
    Route::get('details', 'FrontController@details')->name('productdetails');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('/cart','CartController');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
        Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
        Route::resource('category','CategoriesController');
    });
```

My Error creation Page is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/sv5au9baes9a3x0/1.txt).

The form tag on top creates the error and the form tag on the bottom work fine.

My Controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products=Product::orderBy('id','DESC')->take(4)->get();
        $cartItems = Cart::content();
        return view('cart.index',compact('products','cartItems'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        Cart::add($id,$product->name,1,$product->price);
        return back();
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Cart::update($id,$request->qty);
        return back();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Cart::remove($id);
        return back();
    }
}
```

I want only the top form tag to work. Please Guide me. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your code instead of images of it?

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: Posted my code!

Comment: I'm trying to access cart/{id)

Comment: with which method you are accessing the route for delete delete or normal get

Comment: @HaiderAli i'm accessing the route with action={{"route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}

Comment: yes but you need to do add delete method as well then it will work

Comment: try the cod ein my answer for delete button

Comment: @HaiderAli already done that but still it's the same error.

Comment: can you please also add the view code to question

Comment: @HaiderAli read my post again i've posted it here. 

My Error creation Page is here.

Comment: kindly paste the view code instead of file attachment!

Comment: In the error stack, which file created by you pointing to your error and what error it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Resource controller for the cart. So you should use the delete method for delete button.

```
<form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. You method is not working it shows the same error.

Comment: try it again removed the method post

Answer (score 0):

You may try

`Route::resource('/cart','CartController')->name('cart');`